# PHPExcel and Php MVC Framework

Tags: php, model-view-controller, phpexcel, php-5.3

I'm developing a basic php framework and y have a problem. I want to use PHPExcel for  download reports in excel.

This is my Controller:

```
public function export(){

        require_once ROOT."libs".DS."PHPExcel/PHPExcel.php";        


        header('Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel');
        header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="sites.xls"');
        header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');

        $objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel();  


        $writer = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel5');
        $writer->save('php://output');

    }
```

The PHP library is here:

[image]

When I open the excel file get the following:

```
ÐÏà¡±á;þÿ

þÿÿÿþÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿþÿà…ŸòùOh«‘+'³Ù0¸@Hh€˜
¤°äUntitled SpreadsheetUnknown CreatorUnknown Creator@`Do›ßÎ@`Do›ßÎ
ÌÑB°=¼%r8X"1ÜCalibriàõÿ À

ÌÑ*+‚€Áƒ„&ffffffæ?'ffffffæ?(è?)è?¡"dXX333333Ó?333333Ó?U}$
þÿÕÍÕœ.“—+,ù®0¼HPX`hp
xŽä
WorksheetFeuilles de calculRoot Entryÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿ
```

I hope you can help. Thanks

Comment: Are you opening that file *in Excel*...?

Comment: Well that looks like the content of the Excel file... is this what you see when you open it in MS Excel? Or is it displaying it in the browser?

Comment: It's when I open MS Excel